# How to use custom customer variables in transactional email templates in magento?

Tags: magento

I have added some custom variables to customer and I want to use them in email template.

Here's example how I have added a variable to customer in my installer:

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'companyname', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Company name',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
 $entityTypeId,
 $attributeSetId,
 $attributeGroupId,
 'companyname',
 '999'  //sort_order
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'companyname');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create'));
$oAttribute->save();
```

I try to use this variable in email template:

```
{{var order.getCustomer().getCompanyname()}}
```

But it's not showing. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I done similar task with code like below:

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'attr_name', array(
    'type'      => 'int',
    'input'     => 'select',
    'label'     => 'Attr label',
    'global'    => 1,
    'visible'   => 1,
    'required'  => 1,
    'default'   => '0',
    'user_defined'      => 1,
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
));
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'attr_name');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', 'attr_name')
        ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create'))
        ->save();
}
```

Next have tested it (right now) within "Order new" email `{{var order.getCustomer().getAttrName()}}` and have got correct value.
Try it, might it helps to you.

Comment: I have used it like this `{{var order.getCustomer().getCompanyname()}}` i think it's same than in your solution. Why it's not working for me?

Comment: May be it not visible on emails. May be this attribute has not set to current customer. Try reindex store (System -> Index Managment) and check whether attribute has been set for that customer.

Comment: Now its working! I changed my installer code and added `'global'    => 1,'visible_on_front'  => 1,` Thank you!