# How to print an EAV-value in email template

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I've introduced a custom EAV attribute for the customer object. Let's call it `myvalue`. Within several places in magento, I'm printing the value like this:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getMyvalue();
```

Now, I'd like to print it to the order confirmation email template. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645127/how-to-use-custom-customer-variables-in-transactional-email-templates-in-magento This might help you

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

First, I created a new directory `mydirectory` in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`. In this directory, I put a file `myvalue.phtml` with the following content.

```
 <?php
  $customer=$this->getData('order')->getCustomer();
  print_r($customer->getMyvalue());
 ?>
```

And I've included this block in the email template using this line:

```
 {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='mydirecory/myvalue.phtml' order=$order}}
```